# check the manual that corresponds to your mariadb server version for the right syntax to use near "user" at line 1

Tags: mysql, vb.net, syntax-error

I have a textbox, button, and datagridview in my form. When i click the button, system will grab a table depending on my textbox from the database and show on datagridview.

I getting this error when i click the button. Where am I wrong?

[image: error msg]

here is my dbconn

```
Module mod_dbconn
Public conn As MySqlConnection
Public Sub openDB()
    Dim dbname As String = scr_sales.btn_dbswitch.Text
    Dim server As String = "localhost"
    Dim user As String = "root"
    Dim password As String = ""

    Try
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, user, password, dbname)

        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is my form

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM '" + TextBox1.Text + "'"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt = New DataTable
    Dim cb As MySqlCommandBuilder



    cb = New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
    DataGridView1.Refresh()

    Try
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)

        Dim bsource As New BindingSource
        bsource.DataSource = dt

        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = bsource
        da.Update(dt)

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to build a dynamic table select  so for the table name you don't need the quotes around the tablename

```
 "SELECT * FROM " + TextBox1.Text + " ;"
```

Comment: omg i spent half day on this issue... now you tell me what i need to do is just remove the quotes... finally solved the problem, thx alot!!!

Comment: @vbnewbie   . Sometimes the leaves keep you from seeing the forest